# How do i resolve this date filter issue in a google sheets query?

Tags: google-sheets

Column B on my Transactions Tab shows Dates in standard date format.

This query works to produce a table of my expenses for several medical categories.

Cell B314 has the date 1/1/2021, Cell C314 has 12/31/2021 entered. I just want to show transactions for 2021. This date filter dies not work as it continues to show transactions from 2022 and 2023

=QUERY(Transactions!B1:Transactions!F8094,"Select B,C,D,E Where B >= date '"&TEXT(B314,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B <= date '"&TEXT(C314,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND D= 'Personal - Medical Expense' or D='Personal - Travel' or D='Personal - Medical Insurance' ORDER BY B",1)

The same things happens when I remove the date cell references and enter the full expression:

=QUERY(Transactions!B1:Transactions!F8094,"Select B,C,D,E where B >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/1/2021"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("12/31/2021"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND D= 'Personal - Medical Expense' or D='Personal - Travel' or D='Personal - Medical Insurance' ORDER BY B",1)

I tried many small changes but cannot get it to work. Im a rookie with queries.

Comment: Share a sample work so that we can work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem in `OR` statement. Give a try on below query.

```
=QUERY(Transactions!B1:F8094,"Select B,C,D,E Where B >= date '"&TEXT(B314,"yyyy-mm-dd") & 
"' AND B <= date '"&TEXT(C314,"yyyy-mm-dd")&
"' AND (D= 'Personal - Medical Expense' or D='Personal - Travel' or D='Personal - Medical Insurance') ORDER BY B",1)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That seems to have worked! Im curious what the the date filter was affected by the subsequent use of AND VS OR ?? Would you mind explaining a bit?

Comment: When you were using `OR` without bracketing `(...)` then formula treated it to compare with dates conditions and find always true outside of date ranges because any of condition meet from or statements. When you enclose all `OR` statements by bracket `(...)` then those or statements execute separately and date conditions execute separately and then compare with date conditions.